# Check foreign keys constraints after all inserts statements postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to populate a database before a few scenarios, for this, I added data through my system, and them made a pg_dump command to export the data, however, the inserts statements is sorted alphabetically, and when I run, it will eventually violate foreign keys constraints.

In postgreSQL, is there a way of doing all inserts statements and after that check foreign keys constraints?

Comment: You can define the constraints as `deferrable` then they will be checked when you `commit` the transaction, not when you `insert` the rows. But the SQL script generated by `pg_dump` will add (define) the foreign keys at the end _after_ all data has been inserted, so there is nothing you need to do (unless you generated the dump with `--data-only`)

Comment: I generated as --data-only